# Is there any feature difference of snowflake between AWS and Azure

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have recently completed two migrations from Hadoop to Snowflake on AWS. I am now moving on to work with another customer where snowflake is on Azure. I wanted to know if there are any feature difference between Snowflake on AWS and snowflake on Azure.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not in terms of Snowflake - most customers pick depending on the other systems they use and the deployment (to avoid the extra costs related to data transfer - Snowflake doesn't charge for data load, but AWS and Azure do charge to get the data into the correct deployment if it's not there already)

Answer (score 0):

Metadaten Operations in Azure are slightly slower.
And the maximum filesize ist limited to 256 MB while its 5 GB on AWS and Google.